# Creating Cloudwatch alarm to monitor a log group and then send customized email with log details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

Currently I've setup a Cloudwatch alarm to monitor and capture a particular exception and then to send an email to subscribed email addresses.
The log group would have logs from a ECS task that im running on ECS. So whenever a specif exception occurs (`InvalidMerchantDetailsException` in this case) it will have a log line such as :

`org.abc_service.errors.InvalidMerchantDetailsException: Invalid merchant ID : 123456`

Basically the steps that I have followed are below :

1. Create a metric, metric filter with exception pattern (InvalidMerchantDetailsException) for the specific log group i want to monitor
2. Create the alarm, specify the metric and conditions
3. Create SNS topic with desired email addresses and then configure it to publish when the alarm is triggered.

So I have been able to send the email alerts. However the alerts are very basic, even though it has Alarm name, description, metric name etc it doesnt have any key information from the log.
In here im interested to include the `merchant ID` to the email so it would be pretty useful for the relevant parties.
Is this something that can be done?

Comment: It looks like the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713561/how-to-send-cloudwatch-log-details-via-email?rq=2) will answer your question as well.